# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'asfreq'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a small project trying to make a stock price prediction neural network with python on jupyter notebook.I have all the imports I need and I imported them correctly without an error. I also made sure that I'm importing the csv file correctly.

This is the cell that is giving me the error:

```
a_df = get_dataframe_from_csv("DAX")
a_df = a_df.asfreq('d')
a_df.index
```

Here is the code for the function:

```
def get_dataframe_from_csv(ticker):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(PATH + ticker + '.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    else:
        return df
```

Here is a sample of the csv file. It has no headings/titles:

```
2013.09.05,00:00,8210.80,8257.80,8162.80,8223.50,30335
2013.09.06,00:00,8224.00,8297.00,8171.50,8251.50,33836
2013.09.09,00:00,8246.50,8315.80,8245.30,8301.00,26223
2013.09.10,00:00,8301.50,8477.80,8298.00,8467.00,30111
```

When I run the cell, I get the error that I mentioned in the title.
I'm trying to tell the network that the data it's getting is daily data, but when I try running the cell, I get an error.

I tried writing it as `a_df = a_df.asfreq(freq='d')` but that didn't work.

What are some possible solutions?

Edit: I think the error is that in my csv file, I don't have an index column with the text "Date"..if this is the case, how do I add it

Comment: The interesting part is your function `get_dataframe_from_csv` because it returns 'None'. Please update your post with the code of this function.

Comment: Ok. now update the value of the constant 'PATH'. I think your file is not found. You should print something below `except FileNotFound:` like `print('File not found')`.

Comment: Add a sample of your `DAX.csv` file, please.

Comment: i did but it didnt return any error. i think im getting an error because my csv file doesnt have an index column with the label "Dates"

Comment: let me get the file

Comment: i added the csv file contents, it was a lot so i didnt add it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your function like below:

```
PATH = "C:\\Users\\terry\\Documents\\jupyter projects\\stock\\"
HEADERS = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

def get_dataframe_from_csv(ticker):
    return pd.read_csv(PATH + ticker + '.csv', index_col='DateTime',
                       parse_dates={'DateTime': ['Date', 'Time']},
                       header=None, names=HEADERS)
                       

a_df = get_dataframe_from_csv("DAX")
```

```
>>> a_df
              Open    High     Low   Close  Volume
DateTime                                          
2013-09-05  8210.8  8257.8  8162.8  8223.5   30335
2013-09-06  8224.0  8297.0  8171.5  8251.5   33836
2013-09-09  8246.5  8315.8  8245.3  8301.0   26223
2013-09-10  8301.5  8477.8  8298.0  8467.0   30111
```

Comment: i get an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\terry\\Documents\\jupyter projects\\stock predictorDAX.csv'`

i set my path in a variable like this: `PATH = r"C:\Users\terry\Documents\jupyter projects\stock predictor"
`

not sure why the error shows it like i have double slashes when i used one

Comment: `predictorDAX.csv` -> missing` \\` between the predictor and DAX. This is why I wanted to check your PATH variable

Comment: when i add the`\ ` between the `predictor` and the `"` it highlights the rest of the code as if its part of the PATH variable even though the `"` is closing

Comment: I updated my answer with the PATH variable. : Use it as is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237551/discussion-between-terry-and-corralien).

Comment: i tried your solution and it worked well, but i got an error when trying to forecast, the error was `ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.`

Comment: Did you convert your dataframe with `asfreq`? `a_df.asfreq('d')`

Comment: i fixed it with `a_df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(a_df.index).to_period('D')'

Comment: something is not right  though. my initial issue was fixed yes, but the model is not forecasting possible future prices, on the graph there's no place where the prediction line is trailing off on its own..could it be that my graph is too small? should i just print the predictions in plain text?

Comment: It's an another problem of ML. Do you have enough data to train and to test? If you open a new question, let me know here.

Comment: yes i have enough data to test, i have 2048, i used 1000

Comment: I posted my question [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69345002/ml-neural-network-not-forecasting)